# ng-select: list not updating

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I have the below method that updates the modules array. In the console the result is displayed correctly, but in the ng-select the list is not updated. I tried with `this.modules=[...elements]`, but it's not working also.

```
public onChangeClass(event) {
   this.moduleService.getModulesByLevel(this.form.get("levels").value).subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      let elements = data.filter(module => module.assignClasses.some(item => event.map(el => el.classId).includes(item.classs.classId)));
      this.modules = elements;
      console.log(this.modules);
   })
}

<ng-select [items]="modules" formControlName="module" bindLabel="designation" bindValue="moduleId"></ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ChangeDetectorRef`.

At `@Component` directive, add `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` E.g:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'your-selector',
    templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
```

**At component's constructor, add**

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) // with your other dependencies
```

**At `onChangeClass` method, add**

```
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```

after `this.modules = elements;`

**This should work.**